# Opencl launch concurrent kernels

Tags: concurrency, gpu, opencl, nvidia

As far as I understand, to execute concurrent kernels (in my case same kernel but different I/O data) it must be done by launching unique compute units (streaming multiprocessors -SMs) with apparently their own workgroups.

For example gtx960m has 5 SMs (compute units in Opencl). Launching `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` 5 times asynchronously and out of order, with their own 16x16 (2d) workgroup, will launch all 5 compute units to execute them concurrently? The local memory reported is 64kb. That is for all compute units or each one will have 64kb by its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each CU has either 4 (Maxwell/Pascal) or 2 (Turing/Ampere, AMD) Warps. A Warp is a group of 32 CUDA cores / stream processors in hardware.

All threads running in one Warp have to do exactly the same instructions. Within a Warp, not even branching is possible. Two Warps within a CU can handle different branches, but not different kernels at the same time.

If you execute two kernels in different queues in parallel on your 960m with 5 CUs, Kernel 1 can have for example 3 CUs and kernel 2 can have the remaining 2. But a CU cannot be split to run multiple kernels at the same time.

In OpenCL you can set the workgroup size to some multiple of the Warp size (32). Either 4 (workgroup size 32), 2 (workgroup size 64) or 1 (workgroup size 128 or greater) OpenCL workgroups can be executed at one moment on one Maxwell CU.

The amount of local memory, in your case 64KB, is per CU. So if you have a large workgroup of for example 256 threads, each thread has less local memory available than if you have workgroup size 64, because all threads in the workgroup share the same local memory uf the one CU they run on.

Comment: All kernels (same program) are in the same queue and launced asynchronously in our of order mode. Each workgroup has 256 (16x16 - 2d) workitems or threads. So I am asking again cos I didn't understand your answer, will they executed concurrently? About the local memory, you mean bigger workgroup (more threads) needs more memory? Why is that? The local buffer memory let's say is an array of 12kb. Why this is changing if workgroup has 32 or 256 threads?

Comment: If the kernels are in the same queue, they cannot be executed simultaneously. You'd need 2 queues for that. The asynchronous operation of the queue just means that the clEnqueueNDRangeKernel command is not blocking and the kernel is not executed when you run the enqueue command on the host side. See here https://stackoverflow.com/q/58946050/9178992

Comment: Local memory is per CU and shared between all threads in a workgroup. If you have a larger workgroup, then per thread you have less local memory and also less register space (private memory / temporäre variables) available. __local memory space on GPUs is part of L2 cache. You only need local memory if you want to communicate data between threads within a workgroup. In some cases, like cache tiling in matrix multiplication, this can give you significant speedup.

Comment: I understand. So to run concurrently 5 kernels I need 5 separate queues right? Is like "streams" in the cuda world? My local memory declaration in kernel function is `__local unsigned int* tempArray` which is called from host with the statement `clSetKernelArg(kernelCalc, 1, 1000 * sizeof(integer), NULL)`. So how the hell the size of 1000 * 4 = 4000 bytes in total for local memory is changing if I have 1 thread or 100 threads (workitems)? I thought it remains constant ie ~4KB in this case

Comment: Also is there any way to check with a tool may be to verify that 2 or more CU are executed concurrently?

Comment: Why do you say that I need 2 queues only? Indeed I tried with 2 queues & it worked but more than 2 I had errors ie -52 (`ERROR:clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` & `error occured during context use: CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS error`). The execution is running using "in order" (in out of order I had also errors). I thought that if my GPU has 5 CUs, then 5 queues it will concurrently run the 5 kernels independently. Am I wrong? If I can run only 2 queues for some reason (i don't know) how can I distribute independently requirements of GPU use that comes asynchronously from the host (cpu)?

Comment: Yes, 5 concurrent kernels = 5 queues. Local array size is what you define it to be; but if it's too large, it'll spill to global memory, resulting in large performance loss / errors. If kernel range is large enough, one/multiple concurrent kernels will always use all available CUs. The CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS ierror is not related to the number of queues. Finally, you shouldn't run 5 queues on one device. 1 queue usually performs best because each kernel in itself is parallelized to use all CUs at once.

Comment: Thanks! With "kernel range" I suppose you mean "num of threads". In my case, each workgroup is only 256 threads (16x16), so I don't think is too big. Anyway, for each execution, I create a queue[i] and at the end, I release the queue[i]. I suspect that `clFinish(queue[i])` does not guaranty that execution is already finished before I release the quque[i] despite the fact it says it blocks the next command execution until it finishes. Is there any other way to know that kernel did the job before I release the queue[i]. Using 2 queues I got almost ~30% speedup instead of 1 queue before.

Comment: Another question, if all CUs are busy the next execution kernel would be stalled or it will return with an error?

Comment: Is the error 52 (`ERROR:clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` & `error occured during context use: CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS error`) related somewhat with `out of resources` error? Manual does not refer to anything but the program runs successfully with 1 kernel as well as with 2 concurrent kernels but for 3 or more concurrent kernels, I get this error.

Comment: Yes, kernel range = number of threads = #workgroups * workgroup size. The more workgroups / the larger the kernel range, the more efficient the kernel runs. clFinish is blocking, so the CPU will not continue untill the queue is emptied. If all CUs are busy, the next kernel has to wait / is stalled. Error -52 is invalid kernel argument. Kernel arguments should be either global or constant. For all error codes see here: https://streamhpc.com/blog/2013-04-28/opencl-error-codes/

Comment: Thank you. My input kernel parameters are indeed global (array of buffers for CPU threads data independency) or constant size buffers for local memory as I showed above. Does the release of queue[ I ] deleted also the common content?

Comment: Releasing the queue does not delete the context on that the queue has been created. I don't know if I understood you correctly; does this answer your question?

Comment: All created queues have a common context ie clCreateContext is called only once and multiple times clCreateCommandQueue/clReleaseCommandQueue (CPU thread life cycle)

Comment: I would like to let you know that the root of the Args problem was that some args that didn't change, was out of a for loop that is calling the kernel in the concurrent kernel execution. Thank you for your valuable help at the concurrency level.